# View received json to debug JSONDecoder error

Tags: swift

I am currently using the following flow to call an api and decode the response:

```
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
            .mapError { error -> NetworkClientError in
                print(error)
                return NetworkClientError.network(description: error.localizedDescription)
            }
            .tryMap { element -> Data in
                guard let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    throw NetworkClientError.network(description: URLError(.badServerResponse).localizedDescription)
                }
                return element.data
            }
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: decoder)
            .mapError { error in
                print(error)
                return NetworkClientError.parsing(description: error.localizedDescription)
            }
            .receive(on: queue)
            .retry(retries)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

When i call it i get a 200 response but also a decoding error:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "leagues", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "leagues", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"leagues\", intValue: nil) (\"leagues\").", underlyingError: nil))
parsing(description: "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.")
```

All i want to do is view the json that has been received so that i can see what it is expecting. I can see that The model i have given it says to expect a value `leagues` but this is not what it can find. How can i see what it has found?

Comment: you could try adding `print(String(data: element.data, encoding: .utf8))` between
 `.tryMap { element -> Data in `
 and `guard let httpResponse = ...`

Comment: Read the DecodingError carefully, it's pretty clear: Follow the CodingPath. The JSON doesn't match the model.

Comment: @vadian read the question fully, ive already said that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i resolved this by adding the following after the guard.

```
                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: element.data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {

                        print(json)
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
```

Comment: I guess my `print(String(data: element.data, encoding: .utf8))` didn't do the same thing.

Comment: it does but the output from the above solution is clearer, thanks for your help!

Comment: This will fail if the response is not JSON... Typical case? If you hit some strange response from the back-end, and in this unmanaged case it responses XML/HTML error. This happens a lot. So I'd instead print as previously said the String response to check that. If the issue is about formatting, there are plenty of tools to pretty format JSON.

Comment: Im only using this to debug and view the json, this isnt going into production. Also, the catch is there